# Updating react useState hook nested 2d array

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks, state, use-state

1. Hii I'm trying to update my nested 2d board field state with no success.

Is there any simpler way to store 2d array?

```
export default function Game() {
    const [state, setState] = useState({
        board: [
            [null, "B", null, "B", null, "B", null, "B"],
            ["B", null, "B", null, "B", null, "B", null],
            [null, "B", null, "B", null, "B", null, "B"],
            ["X", null, "X", null, "X", null, "X", null],
            [null, "X", null, "X", null, "X", null, "X"],
            ["G", null, "G", null, "G", null, "G", null],
            [null, "G", null, "G", null, "G", null, "G"],
            ["G", null, "G", null, "G", null, "G", null],
        ],
        greyTurn: true,
        chess: null,
        dest: null,
    });




const update = () => {
        setState(prevState => ({...prevState, board[0,0]: 'G'}))
    }


return (
<>
   <button onClick={update}></button>
<>
)
```

2. Changing the update function to this one

> const update = () => {
> const newState = [...state.board];
> newState[0][0] = 'G';
> }

actually make the update state, but I don't understand why, didn't I just create deep state.board copy? why manipulating this deep copy actually make change in my state.board?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

your state is an object, and your board is a property of that object. when you do:

```
setState(prevState => ({...prevState, board[0,0]: 'G'})
```

you are trying to set a `board[0,0]`(which will throw an error) property with value `G` to your `state`, not modifying your `board` array.

you would need to first copy your board. Also you would copy the nested array you want to modify. then you could return your next state as:

```
    setState(prevState => {
      const newBoard = [...prevState.board];
      newBoard[0] = [...newBoard[0]];
      newBoard[0,0] = 'G';
      return { ...prevState, board: newBoard }
    })
```

With hooks you can break down your state into multiple states, instead storing all in one state object. that would be better to handle the state pieces independently.

Regardless, to update an array you would still need to create a copy then change the desired index:

```
export default function Game() {
    const [board, setBoard] = useState([
            [null, "B", null, "B", null, "B", null, "B"],
            ["B", null, "B", null, "B", null, "B", null],
            [null, "B", null, "B", null, "B", null, "B"],
            ["X", null, "X", null, "X", null, "X", null],
            [null, "X", null, "X", null, "X", null, "X"],
            ["G", null, "G", null, "G", null, "G", null],
            [null, "G", null, "G", null, "G", null, "G"],
            ["G", null, "G", null, "G", null, "G", null],
        ]);
    const [greyTurn, setgreyTurn] = useState(true);
    const [chess, setChess] = useState(null);
    const [dest, setDest] = useState(null);

    const updateBoard = () => {
        setBoard(prevBoard => {
          const board = [...prevBoard];
          board[0] = [...board[0]];
          board[0,0] = 'G';
          return board;
        })
    }
```

Comment: I am trying to manage all of them in one state, so this solution will now work for me.

Answer (score 2):

```js
import React, {useState} from 'react';

export default function Game() {
  const [state, setState] = useState({
    board: [
      [null, 'B', null, 'B', null, 'B', null, 'B'],
      ['B', null, 'B', null, 'B', null, 'B', null],
      [null, 'B', null, 'B', null, 'B', null, 'B'],
      ['X', null, 'X', null, 'X', null, 'X', null],
      [null, 'X', null, 'X', null, 'X', null, 'X'],
      ['G', null, 'G', null, 'G', null, 'G', null],
      [null, 'G', null, 'G', null, 'G', null, 'G'],
      ['G', null, 'G', null, 'G', null, 'G', null],
    ],
    greyTurn: true,
    chess: null,
    dest: null,
  });

  const update = () => {
    setState((prevState) => {
      const { board } = prevState;
      board[0][0] = 'G';
      return { ...prevState, board };
    });
  };

  return (
    <>
      <button onClick={update}></button>
    </>
  );
}
```

This is how to update the first index of the first array in the board.